# Fallback Image on Post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I recently started getting into Coding and I'm having trouble modifying a Wordpress Theme.

The Code is looking like this:

```html
<div class="wt-formtheme wt-formprojectinfo wt-formcategory">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group form-group-label" id="wt-service-container">
      <div class="wt-labelgroup" id="service-drag">
        <label for="file" class="wt-job-file">
          <span class="wt-btn" id="service-btn"><?php esc_html_e('Select File', 'workreap'); ?></span>          
        </label>
        <span><?php esc_html_e('Drop files here to upload', 'workreap'); ?></span>
        <em class="wt-fileuploading"><?php esc_html_e('Uploading', 'workreap'); ?><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <ul class="wt-attachfile uploaded-placeholder"></ul>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I want to check if the Person which is posting has inserted a Picture and if not I want to display a Fallback Image from my Wordpress Library.

Is it possible to do so in this Line of Code or do I have to edit something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to do that in the code that proccess the form

Answer (score 1):

You can do that once the form has been submitted.

But the correct way to handle this situation is to just set a default image wherever the image read is happening.

For example: If you are going to display this image in a post. On that side just check if image exists for that post and if not then the default image can show.

This will save you from loading multiple copies of default image either in folder or in the database. (*If you are storing this in database then just put default value of that column as the path of default image, this will require no coding at all*)